# How do I join already joined pivot table with another table

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot, pivot-table

So I have already joined pivot table and i want to join it with another one:

```
Customers  Name  Surname   
  1        Adam  Sandler
  2        John   Smith
```

original tables were:

```
ID     Food 
1      Chicken  
2      Pork
```

and

```
 Customers  Food  Cost   
    1        1     45
    1        2     12
    2        2     12
```

How do I make it look like this:

```
Customers   Chicken   Pork   Name   Surname
   1          45       12    Adam   Sandler
   2         NULL      12    John    Smith
```

Comment: First decide which rdbms product you use^ mysql or ms sql server. Then show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: ok thanks. I didn't noticed that I puted that there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @tab1 table(id int,food char(50))
declare @tab2 table(customers int, food int, cost int)
declare @tab3 table(customers int,name char(100),surname char(100))
insert into @tab1 values ('1','Chicken'),('2','Pork')
insert into @tab2 values (1,1,45),(1,2,12),(2,2,12)
insert into @tab3 values (1,'Adam','Sandler'),(2,'John','Smith')


select * from 
(select t2.customers,t3.name,t3.surname,t2.cost,t1.food from @tab2 t2,@tab3 t3, @tab1 t1 where t2.customers=t3.customers and t1.id=t2.food) a
pivot ( max(a.cost) for a.food in ([Chicken],[Pork]))p
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You can try this one.

Sample Table:

```
    ---Table @Customer
    ID    NAME     SURNAME
    ----- -------- -------
    1     Adam     Sandler
    2     John     Smith

    --- Table @Food
    ID          NAME
    ----------- --------
    1           Chicken
    2           Pork

    --- Table @FoodCost
    ID          CustomerID  FoodId      Cost
    ----------- ----------- ----------- --------
    1           1           1           45.00
    2           1           2           12.00
    3           2           2           12.00
```

You can JOIN first the Customer table before pivoting it.

```
            ----I used ***Stuff function, 
            ----to determine content of table @food- column name dynamically.  
            DECLARE @DynamicColumn NVARCHAR(354) = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                                    ', '
                                                                    + QUOTENAME(f.NAME)
                                                           FROM     @FoodCost FC
                                                                    LEFT JOIN @Food F ON F.ID = fc.FoodId
                                                         FOR
                                                           XML PATH('')
                                                         ), 1, 2, '')



            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    DROP TABLE #tmpTable
                END

            CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
                (
                  Customer INT ,
                  Food NVARCHAR(50) ,
                  [Name] NVARCHAR(50) ,
                  Surname NVARCHAR(50) ,
                  Cost NUMERIC(22, 2)
                )

            INSERT  INTO #tmpTable
                    ( Customer ,
                      Food ,
                      Name ,
                      Surname ,
                      Cost
                    )
                    SELECT  Fc.CustomerID ,
                            f.NAME [Food] ,
                            c.NAME ,
                            SURNAME ,
                            fc.Cost
                    FROM    @FoodCost FC
                            LEFT JOIN @Customer C ON C.ID = FC.CustomerID  --- <---Joining Customer Table
                            LEFT JOIN @Food F ON F.ID = fc.FoodId 


            DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
            SET @SQL = N'
                
                        SELECT 
                        Customer,
                        ' + @DynamicColumn + ',
                        Name,
                        Surname
                        FROM (
                            SELECT Customer,Food,Name, Surname,Cost FROM #tmpTable
                        )P pivot ( SUM(p.Cost) for p.Food in (' + @DynamicColumn + '))PVT'


            EXEC (@SQL)
```

Result:

```
    Customer    Chicken  Pork     Name    Surname
    --------    -------  -------  ------  -------
    1           45.00    12.00    Adam    Sandler
    2           NULL     12.00    John    Smith

    (2 row(s) affected)
```

***[Stuff function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql)